# Loading local STL files

Tags: xtk

I tried referencing a local STL file for the skull example and changed:

skull.file = 'http://x.babymri.org/?skull.vtk';

to:

skull.file = 'file:///C:/graham/cad_files/rubber_duck.stl';

but I don't see my model.

The STL file is a binary file, and I see from the API document that these are supported.

I'm using Windows and am sure that the file:///C:/... format is correct.

I'm using jsfiddle and saved the file as an external resource:

jsfiddle.net/gmseed/TTBr2/6/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to drop the file in slicedrop.com?

If it works, it means there is something wrong in your code, if it doesn't work, it is related to XTK

The jsfiddle link is not working because the file your are trying to pass is not available to the public. (it is sitting on your computer, and the link only works from your computer)

You could use drop box or google drive to host your file instead.

Thanks

Comment: I added a url reference to the stl on Google Drive that hass public accessibility. I still don't see the model.